# Changing values in a dataframe based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is the dataframe which I have:

```
import pandas as pd
list = ['RK','G', 'CUSTOM', 'CUSTOM', 'KL', 'kj']
df=pd.DataFrame(list,columns=['A'])
```

What I would like to do here is to find out all the entries in column `A` which are equal to `CUSTOM` and replace it with `CUSTOM1` AND `CUSTOM2`.

The output should be:

```
       A
0      RK
1      G
2    CUSTOM1
3    CUSTOM2
4     KL
5     kj
```

Had there been 3 `CUSTOM` instead of 2, the output should be `CUSTOM1` , `CUSTOM2` and `CUSTOM3`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `cumsum` + `np.where` -

```
m = df.A.eq('CUSTOM')
df.A = np.where(m, df.A + m.cumsum().astype(str), df.A)

df
         A
0       RK
1        G
2  CUSTOM1
3  CUSTOM2
4       KL
5       kj
```

---

A similar solution using `pd.Series.where`/`mask` -

```
df.A = df.A.where(~m, df.A + m.cumsum().astype(str))
```

Or,

```
df.A = df.A.mask(m, df.A + m.cumsum().astype(str))
```

```
df
         A
0       RK
1        G
2  CUSTOM1
3  CUSTOM2
4       KL
5       kj
```

Comment: 3 *pythonic* solutions to the same problem. Great work.

Comment: @VenkateshMalhotra You're welcome, happy coding. ;-)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga If we're being PC, then you mean "pandaic" :D

Comment: @VenkateshMalhotra *pandonic* ;)

Answer (score 2):

By using `cumcount` + `count`

```
df.A=df.A+(df.groupby('A').cumcount()+1).where(df.groupby('A').A.transform('count').ne(1),'').astype(str)
df.A
Out[208]: 
0         RK
1          G
2    CUSTOM1
3    CUSTOM2
4         KL
5         kj
dtype: object
```

Comment: Hello, nice solution :-)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ yours as well :-)

Comment: That was awesome as always Wen. Thank you.

Comment: @VenkateshMalhotra aha yw

Answer (score 2):

I'm interested to see how this approach will work compared to the others:

```
In [10]: import itertools

In [11]: counter = itertools.count(1)

In [12]: df.A.str.replace(r"CUSTOM", lambda x: f"CUSTOM{next(counter)}")
Out[12]:
0         RK
1          G
2    CUSTOM1
3    CUSTOM2
4         KL
5         kj
Name: A, dtype: object
```

Note, you need `pandas` version >= 0.20.0 for `pd.Series.str.replace` to accept a callable.

If you don't have Python 3.6 f-strings, you can also just do:

```
In [14]: counter = itertools.count(1)

In [15]: df.A.str.replace(r"CUSTOM", lambda x: "CUSTOM{}".format(next(counter)))
Out[15]:
0         RK
1          G
2    CUSTOM1
3    CUSTOM2
4         KL
5         kj
Name: A, dtype: object
```

Comment: Nice! Might want to add a version without f-strings for <3.6 versions.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with a loop:

```
count = 1
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['A'] == 'CUSTOM':
        row['A'] += str(count)
        count += 1

print(df)

#output
         A
0       RK
1        G
2  CUSTOM1
3  CUSTOM2
4       KL
5       kj
```